# Mirror class from existing library and implement Parcelable

Tags: android, class

What is the best method to mirror a class and implement Parcelable?

The reason for this is because I am using a library, but I also need to broadcast a object, and in order for me to do that I need to implement Parcelable without editing the original class in the library?

UPDATE:

- The library is opensource, but it's written in pure java.
- I prefer to not make changes in the class it self as I commit to this repo, and would like to keep the library pure java.
- The library is the OBD2 java library by pires.
- The class is the OBDCommand.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: 
So I looked at [pires/obd-java-api on GitHub](https://github.com/pires/obd-java-api) and now I see your problem:  The `OBDCommand` class is an abstract class that has four abstract subclasses and *forty-three* concrete subclasses.

Yikes.

Making `Parcel` factories for all these classes using reflection is not something I would want to do. So I think your best bet is:

- Talk to Paulo Pires about making `OBDCommand` implement `Serializable`.  Once `OBDCommand` implements `Serializable`, someone should go through all the subclasses and make sure that all the fields can be serialized and that all the transient fields are marked `transient`.
- Then you can have a class like this:

  ```
  public class ParcelableOBDCommand implements Parcelable {

      private OBDCommand mObdCommand;

      public ParcelableOBDCommand(OBDCommand obdCommand) {
          mObdCommand = obdCommand;
      }

      public OBDCommand getObdCommand() {
          return mObdCommand;
      }

      @Override
      public int describeContents() {
          return 0;
      }

      @Override
      public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

          try {
              ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
              out.writeObject(mObdCommand);
              dest.writeInt(baos.toByteArray().length);
              dest.writeByteArray(baos.toByteArray());
          } catch (IOException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
          }
      }

      public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableOBDCommand> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableOBDCommand>() {

          @Override
          public ParcelableOBDCommand createFromParcel(Parcel source) {

              try {
                  byte[] bytesIn = new byte[source.readInt()];
                  source.readByteArray(bytesIn);
                  ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesIn));
                  return new ParcelableOBDCommand((OBDCommand) in.readObject());
              } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                  throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
              }
          }

          @Override
          public ParcelableOBDCommand[] newArray(int size) {
              return new ParcelableOBDCommand[size];
          }

      };
  }
  ```

Note that this only works if `OBDCommand` implements `Serializable`.

Also note that the whole purpose of `Parcelable` was to get rid of the reflection overhead of `Serializable`, so we are kind of defeating the whole purpose here.  An "OBD Command" is really just a handful of bytes, so Paulo may have a better idea  of how to serialize this family of classes.  Plus it depends on how you are using the classes in your broadcasting service, maybe you don't need to save everything in a `Parcel` for your service broadcast.  But the strategy is: Implement a (pure Java, non-Android) way to read/write the `OBDCommand` subclasses at the `OBDCommand` level, then write a `Parcelable` class that uses the pure Java mechanism under the hood.

---

- Is this an open source library where you have source code access?

  You can create a `Parcelable` implementation that uses reflection to read the object field values and write them to the `Parcel`, and the `Parcelable.Creator` factory can recreate the object using `Class.newInstance()` and use reflection to write the values from the `Parcel` into the new object.  Downside: Updating the library to a new revision may break your `Parcelable` code. However, if you have to deserialize any objects stored using the earlier version, at least there is a possibility of reading the values of the old version from the `Parcel` and writing them to the new version, working around what you don't have values for.
- Is this not open source, but the class you want to mirror implements `Serializable`?

  You can serialize the object to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then write the bytes to the `Parcel`.  The `Parcelable.Creator` factory would then read the bytes and create a `ByteArrayInputStream` from which the object can be deserialized.  Downside:  If your `Parcel` is being stored somewhere such as in a database, and the library is updated to a new revision, trying to deserialize the stored object will fail if the class hasn't handled deserializing an older version.
- None of the above?

  You can decompile and grok the class, then use reflection to read and write the field values as with the open source strategy.  Downside: you have to decompile and grok the class.  And you would have to do this every time a new library is released to check if anything changed.

If you want a more detailed answer, add more details to your question: Which class, which library, does it get revised periodically, etc. etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have updated my question

Comment: Updated my answer.  The `OBDCommand` class will need to have some method of serialization added to it that your `Parcelable` class can use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and assistance. I will have to look into your suggestions